# Jackson: final field written to after it is set by @JsonCreator?

Tags: java, json, security, jackson

It seems Jackson uses reflection to write additional attributes directly into fields even if a `@JsonCreator` constructor was used and the field is marked as `final`.

Example:

```
public class Test {
    static class X {
        final String s;

        @JsonCreator
        public X(@JsonProperty("a") String a) {
            s = "s";
        }

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void ds() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        X x = om.readValue("{`a`:``, `s`: `t`}".replace('`', '"'), X.class);
        assertEquals("s", x.s);
    }
}
```

The assert will fail with `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[s]> but was:<[t]>`.

Is this behavior documented anywhere? Is there anyway to disable this globally?

Also, I think this is a very dangerous design: if there are some value that should be read-only to the client, this effectively allows the client to set them even if the class is well designed according to normal immutable class guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: yes, Jackson allows deserialization of all visible and not just those for which `@JsonCreator` property exists. So it is possible to set a smaller set of properties via constructor, and others via setters or fields. This may be needed for some cases like cyclic types.

As to how to prevent use of `s` for deserialization here. An obvious way is to add `@JsonIgnore` for field, although if so you will also need `@JsonProperty` for `getS()` to avoid both being removed.

But there are other settings as well, in `MapperFeature`.

- `ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS`: if you disable this, `final` fields are never used directly for deserialization
- `INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS`: if you disable this, then neither fields nor setters are "pulled in" in cases where they are not otherwise visible (for fields, `public` is needed to be visible; for setters, even `private` is fine)

So may want to disable one or both settings.